# Why doesn't R.color.white work where Color.WHITE does?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources

I'm trying to set the background of a very simple layout:

```
  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.simple_layout);
```

This works:

```
  ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

But this doesn't:

```
  ll.setBackgroundColor(R.color.white);
```

And yes, I verified that `R.color.white` is defined in a colors.xml file under `/res/values`.

What am I missing?

Comment: what is R.color.white defined as?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel `<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>` but I already found the root of the problem. See below & I will accept it in 5 minutes.

Comment: If you're using Eclipse, make sure you have the latest ADT installed. The Lint plugin will actually mark this as an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `ll.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white)`

Comment: You're right. I forgot about the distinction between color value and color resource id. Sometimes I could be so blind... and the compiler didn't complain about it because they're both `int`. Another way is to convert the resource to color: `getResources().getColor(int);`

Comment: Here in the future we are using `ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white)`

Answer (score 1):

As @Ali points out when you have it set in XML it becomes a resource.  This is very confusing obviously because you don't think of it as a resource, you think of it as a value. But just like all the other resources, it is a resource. So yes, you have to use setBackgroundResource()